# Pokemon Trading Card Game Online for Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, games

Is possibilite to play Pokemon Trading Card Game Online in a Ubuntu 14?

There are a link [here](http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/play-online/download/) but I tried to use Wine, but appear a massege error.

This game run only for Windows and Mac OS.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an error with the installer. If you have a Windows machine somewhere, you can install it and then use Wine to run the executable. You can see more at the [Wine AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30004).